# Clean URLs are broken in MAMP

Tags: uri

I'm using MAMP on os x 10.6.

Until this morning clean URLs where working on about 20 different D6 and D7 installations without problems.

All of a sudden clean URLs are broken on all installations. I'm not aware of having changed something in the MAMP or apache configuration.

Things I already checked:

- `phpinfo()` tells me that mod_rewrite is loaded.
- I did not change any .htaccess files

Do you have any idea on where to look at?

Update: I think the .htaccess files are not loaded at all. I can write gibberish into the file and there are no error messages at all.

Comment: did u try clearing your cache ?

Comment: With Drupal it seems that advice is equivalent to telling a Windows user to "Restart their computer." :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.htaccess* files are ignored if the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive is set to *None*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After all it turned out, that i changed the path to my drupal installations from ../PHP/.. to ../php/.. . I missed the fact that this path is stored inside httpd.conf by MAMP makeing the AllowOverride useless.